# gganimate plot not showing and saving bunch of .png's

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to replicate a simple example about `gganimate` from [here](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html). The problem is simple `ggplot` part works fine but when I add `transition_states` `rstudio` starts rendering and then saves bunch of `gganim_plotXXXX.png` files and doesn't show the expected animation.

First question is obviously: Am I doing something wrong so that animation doesn't work?

Second question is: Is saving bunch of .png files standard for `gganimate`?

Thanks in advance

```
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
         geom_point()

anim <- p + 
  transition_states(Species,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1)
anim
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran your code and got this error:

> Error in l$setup_layer(d, plot) : attempt to apply non-function

And then, I installed the [`png`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/png/index.html) and [`gifski`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gifski/index.html) packages and restart the R-Studio. It's working. I think, you can try this.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried installing gifski but did not restart rstudio afterwards. Installing png too and restarting solved the problem.